# How can I configure permissions, etc. on localhost web server to allow PHP programs to access attached USB Camera

Tags: php, camera, sandbox

I originally asked this question on **Ask Differently**, but the administrator said it was "too broad" for that group and that I should ask it here.

*I am trying to create a PHP program which will run on localhost and needs to take snapshots from attached USB camera devices (the camera array peripheral that I am developing).*

I am doing development on **Mac OS X Mojave** running on **MacBook Pro**. I ultimately will deploys to kiosks which have either an embedded Mac Mini running Mac OS X, or an embedded Raspberry Pi running Linux. The custom camera array HW I am developing is also embedded in this kiosk.

I am currently using **imagesnap** on the Mac and plan to us **fswebcam** on Linux to take pictures programmatically.

I've set up the **local Apache Web Server** that I access as **localhost**. I also have **PHP 7.1.23** installed.

I have written a PHP program (see below) that should list the available cameras connected to the computer using *imagesnap -l* and then it should take an image with each listed camera using *imagesnap -d*.

If I run this PHP program in CLI mode from the terminal under my own userID, it it listed the camera and took and saved the image just fine.

However, my intended deployment will be in a kiosk, with a webpage interface that calls this PHP program when images are to be taken.

Unfortunately there's a problem. The symptoms are clear:

When the PHP program is running in CLI mode with my userID it takes images fine and writes them to the appropriate subdirectory of the web directory.

```
% php ../imagesnaptest.php
imagesnap -l  RETURNS 'Video Devices:
<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x7fda89438500 [FaceTime HD Camera][DJH6095K5ZEG1HPBB]>
' 
FaceTime HD Camera is a valid camera. 
camerasArray = 
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "FaceTime HD Camera"
}

imagesnap -d 'FaceTime HD Camera' /Users/myiuserid/Sites/sonascan/scans/img5cd115d73d2b5.jpg  RETURNS 'Capturing image from device "<AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x7fb27b32dbb0 [FaceTime HD Camera][DJH6095K5ZEG1HPBB]>"...'

Captured 1 images from  cameras.
IMAGING COMPLETE.
```

But when that php program is invoked with an HTTP call from a browser, it runs as **_www** and can't seem to access the cameras and no images are saved to the web directory. But there is no error message explaining why imagesnap failed (or even acknowledging that it had).

```
% imagesnap -l RETURNS '' 
camerasArray = 
array(0) { } 
No valid cameras were found!
```

I've opened up the permissions of my web directory to be **rwx by all**, and this difference in behaviors remained unchanged.

It was suggested to me that my problem is a permissions misconfiguration issue because normally the **_www** webserver user doesn't have access to attached USB devices like cameras. However, no one suggested how I could change that.

In exploring the suggestions I have been given to date, I experimented with making **imagesnap** owned by **_www**, or even **root**, and *even setting the setuid bit on the program.* That did not resolve the problem.  Instead it introduced a new error which generated the error message:

`*2019-05-06 19:56:44.081 imagesnap[60072:14580598] The application with bundle ID (null) is running setugid(), which is not allowed*`.

commenter *@nohillside* wrote:

> "This can be a simple access permission issue, this can be an Apache
>   misconfiguration, this can be a problem coming from SIP (System Integrity Protection), sandboxing or
>   full disk access permissions, this can be something else. Without more
>   details about the setup and some digging on your part (eg if you
>   replace imagesnap with a shell script which just logs itself, does it
>   work) any answer can only be guesswork."

Following up on *@nohillside*'s suggestion I replaced **imagesnap** with a program that doesn't access the camera ("**/usr/local/bin/python3 -h**" and there is no error when the program is changed. So I am thinking it has something to do with the *camera access* that **imagesnap** needs.

It makes sense to me that this might have something to do with **SIP** or **sandboxing**, but I have no idea how to change and test alternative SIP or sandbox configurations.  If you are knowledgable about how to configure these and have suggestions for me to test, Please describe more precisely how to change this configuration.

*How can I learn more about how to configure my web server to allow it to access my camera in this way?* And where can I learn more about how SIP and sandboxing security normally work, and how I should adjust them for situations like I've just described.

```
<?php

if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") { $nl= PHP_EOL; }  //PHP is running in command line
else {  $nl= "<br />"; } // PHP is running in browser }

function getListOfCameras() 
{
    global $nl;

    $imagesnaplist = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/imagesnap -l");
    echo "imagesnap -l  RETURNS '" . $imagesnaplist ."' $nl"; 

    $cameraDeviceArray = explode(PHP_EOL,$imagesnaplist );
    unset ($cameraDeviceArray[0]); // Throw away "Video Devices:" line in element [0]
    $cameraDeviceArray = array_values($cameraDeviceArray); // Reassign elements in array to start at [0] again

    $matchedCameras = 0;
    $camerasArray  =array();
    foreach ($cameraDeviceArray as $key => $value)
    {
            preg_match("/\[(.*?)\]/", $value, $matches);
            if ($matches[1] != "") 
            {
                $camerasArray[$matchedCameras] = $matches[1];
                echo $camerasArray[$matchedCameras]. " is a valid camera. $nl";
                $matchedCameras++;
        }
    }
    return $camerasArray;
}


function takeAPhoto($camera, $filename) 
{
    global $nl;
    $status = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/imagesnap -d '$camera' $filename ");
    echo "imagesnap -d '$camera' $filename  RETURNS '" . $status . "'$nl"; 
    return $status;     
}


function takeAllPhotos($camerasArray) 
{
    global $nl;
    $numberTaken = 0;
    if (count($camerasArray) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($camerasArray as $camera)
        {
            $cameraNumber = $numberTaken;
            $filename = "/Users/myiuserid/Sites/sonascan/scans/img" . uniqid() . ".jpg";
            $status = takeAPhoto($camera, $filename); 
            $numberTaken++;      
        }
        return $numberTaken;
    } else 
    {
        die("No valid cameras were found!$nl");
    }
}

$camerasArray =  getListOfCameras();
echo "camerasArray = $nl";
var_dump($camerasArray);
echo "$nl";

$numberTaken = takeAllPhotos($camerasArray);
echo "$nl" . "Captured $numberTaken images from $numberOfCameras cameras.$nl";
echo "IMAGING COMPLETE.$nl";

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a _programming_ issue, but rather like a system configuration issue.

Comment: I guess that is the problem. I don't know if it is a programming issue or if it is a system configuration issue.  Over on Ask Differently they told me to take it to Stack Overflow, because they think it is a programming issue.  Here, you think it is a System Configuration issue and so should go back there. Going back and forth won't solve this problem. Admittedly, It will probably take a really superior developer who also has a really good grasp of Mac and Linux System Configuration.   I've provided the code so it should be reproducible if such a genius member is curious to resolve it.